# Automatically show form value on page load or submit using .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to find the simplest, non-expert-coder solution to displaying a search query.

I have a search form where onclick of the submit button it displays the form value underneath. This is the code:

```
<input type="text" name="searchfield" id="searchfield" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitSearch" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('searchfield').value" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

The page reloads on submit rather than going to another page.

Is there a simple way to manipulate my code do display the value in the output div **automatically *upon page load***, rather than onclick?

So whatever was placed in the search box will automatically be displayed once the page loads after refresh or submit. If nothing was entered, then nothing will show.

Comment: Is it ok to do it on serverside with PHP?

Comment: PHP could work yes

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, but this would do the job:

```
<input type="text" name="searchfield" id="searchfield" value="" />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('searchfield').value">Submit</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

And using PHP,

```
<input type="text" name="searchfield" id="searchfield" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitSearch" value="Submit" />
<div id="output">
<?php
if($_GET['searchfield'])
    echo $_GET['searchfield'];
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Remember to sanitize it before outputting it to the screen.

Comment: Thanks.. it works by showing the value onclick, but once the page refreshes it is removed from the output DIV ??

Comment: @Sam it's obvious, it's not stored anywhere. is the page getting refreshed on clicking the button?

Comment: Yea, the form submits to the same page. That's why I'm trying to find a solution where it shows upon refresh/page reload, instead of storing. As I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: Ah.. I've just figured something. The script I'm using submits this form using JQuery. That must be why the $_GET php code isn't working?